# I want to create an extension to login to helium10

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome-extension, browser, server-side-rendering

I want to create an extension to login to helium10.if a user is login in a computer then in other chrome profiles , on click extension login button ,he should login to account. they are using server side rendering for form action posting and also setting cookies from server .I can store tokens or credentials on any server if got solution by storing it. If any possible solution please let me know

I try to setting token button i does not as it is setted by server and as per Same Origin Policy i cannot do it by injecting script using extension.And i also try to post form using javascript but it has a recapcha step there.and i think form is posting on server and website has csrf token also like

```
`<form id="login-form" class="login-form" action="/user/signin" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="Z7XW-jeFdMRmhDgiLqFYZEGdUmrI_J9hHiUa5QZ4Z-NS3p-     9fuI5nBTrV0tiwxIMIKoIUqCR1i5qSHCmdgsIlw==">
</form>`
```